# export environment variable from a makefile to the system

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

For one of my project, I need to add something to an env var from a makefile.

Here's a the sandboxed problem :

First, the makefile

```
all:
    $(shell source <(echo export MYVAR=$(MYVAR):otherstuff))
```

And what I'm trying to achieve

```
export MYVAR=stuff
make
echo $MYVAR
```

So technically, MYVAR should contains stuff:otherstuff. But instead of that I got a bash error

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `source <(echo export MYVAR=$MYVAR:otherstuff)'
```

I don't know what I did wrong, the command worked outside of the makefile.

Thanks!

Comment: Child processes (such as `make`) cannot affect the environment of the parent process (your shell) for all practical purposes.  You will need to rethink your requirement.

Comment: or rely on writing the value of `AYY` to a `/tmp` file and then reading from that file in the shell script (not recommended, but if you must, then remember to include code to remove any existing `/tmp` file before starting, and cleaning up afterwards). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter do you have any examples ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so how can I interfere with the env var. Would a makefile nested in a makefile (yo dawg) do the trick ?

Comment: Trying to use `make` to set an environment variable in your shell is fundamentally the wrong thing to be doing.  There really isn't a right way to do it.  You can create a shell script to do it — call it `env-setting-script.sh`.  You'd then use `. env-setting-script.sh` (or `source env-setting-script.sh`) to set the environment in your shell.  Or add it to your profile or `.bashrc` file, or whatever. Using `make` in the process is … not going to make life easy. You could have `make` create the `env-setting-script.sh` file, I suppose, but you still have to do the dot operation in your shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the answer, I'll find an other way to do what I want. I found it weird that a child process can't affect the env var of his parent.

Comment: You must be used to non-Unix systems.  To people used to using Unix, it seems weird that a child should ever be allowed to modify the environment of its parent process.  How's a process to keep control of its own environment if its children can make arbitrary changes to it at arbitrary times?  The security risks alone are astronomical.

Comment: I've been using Unix systems for the past 2 years, but now that you say it, it makes sens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> And what I'm trying to achieve
>
> ```
> export MYVAR=stuff
> make
> echo $MYVAR
> ```
>
> So technically, MYVAR should contains stuff:otherstuff.

As was mentioned in the comments, you can't do it. A copy of  environment is inherited from the parent process (the shell where you perform `export MYVAR=stuff`) by the child process (the `make` call), and whatever the child process does with the variable, would be visible to the `make` itself, or its own child processes. But never the parent.

Generally, when I need to export some information from the `Makefile`, I provision special targets for the purpose, e.g.:

```
print-env:
    @echo export MYVAR=$(MYVAR):otherstuff ";"
    @echo export MYOTHERVAR=helloworld ";"
```

Now when you do `make print-env`, it would produce the output like this:

```
export MYVAR=stuff:otherstuff ;
export MYOTHERVAR=helloworld ;
```

Using the makefile we have generated commands, which could be easily copy-pasted from the output into command prompt to execute them.

Though it is possible and doable, I would advise against the feeding of make's output to the shell directly:

```
eval "`make print-env`"
```

or even more radical:

```
`make print-env`
```

since `make` output is generally unstable, and might accidentally contain output of other rules, which might confuse the shell.